# CSV multi input - i want it on one line!

Tags: magento-1.9, csv

Hello there to make things dead simple when i upload a CSV i want attributes to be able to upload on one line instead of multiple lines, same with images, if you look at this screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKCHm.jpg
the vesa_layered_nav attributes has 2 lines under each other, i would like them to input like this
100 x 100; 150 x 150  (doesnt have to be a ; just as long as its on one line!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following blog entry by Ashley Schroder: http://www.aschroder.com/2012/09/improving-magento-importexport-module-with-better-file-format-and-google-docs-integration/. There, he describes the necessary changes for having those values in one line, in his case separated by a pipe (|).